# Layer is being add to 2 groups instead of 1

Tags: qgis, postgis, pyqgis

I'm trying to create 3 group layers, depending on parameters of two lists, but *reg_imobiliarios* layer is added to *auxiliar* and *referencia* groups.

In short, all the layers are in the correct group, except *reg_imobiliarios*, that I would like to be only in *referencia* group.

Note: I'm using postgis tag, because maybe is a problem in my database, but I think is improbable.

This is the legend before:

[image: before]

And after running the code:

[image: and add to each one]

The results of Python console:
[image]

```
editableLayers = {'aux_area':'auxiliar', 'aux_invasao':'auxiliar',
 'aux_linha':'auxiliar', 'aux_ponto':'auxiliar', 'aux_unificar':'auxiliar',
 'contratos':'ctgeo', 'cotas':'ctgeo', 'imoveis_alienados':'ctgeo',
 'laaa':'ctgeo','lote_legal':'ctgeo', 'cotas_reg_imobiliarios':'referencia',
 'reg_imobiliarios':'referencia'}
deleted_layers = {'aux_area': 'auxiliar', 'cotas': 'ctgeo', 'reg_imobiliarios': 'referencia'}
root = QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot()
auxiliar = root.addGroup('auxiliar')
ctgeo = root.addGroup('ctgeo')
referencia = root.addGroup('referencia')

for layerTable, layerSchema in editableLayers.items():
    for tableDeleted, schemaDeleted in deleted_layers.items(): 
        if layerTable == tableDeleted:
            print(layerTable)
            print(tableDeleted)
            while True:
                print('entrou no while')
                layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName(tableDeleted)[0] 
                QgsProject.instance().removeMapLayer(layer.id())              
                uri.setConnection("LPOSTDES-CL2", "5432", "ugpi", user, passwd)                                 
                uri.setDataSource(schemaDeleted, tableDeleted, "geom")                                       
                layer = QgsVectorLayer(uri.uri(False), tableDeleted, "postgres")                
                QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(layer)                             

                if layerTable == layer.name() and layerSchema == auxiliar.name():
                    print('entrou no auxiliar')
                    print(layerTable)
                    print(layerSchema)
                    vlayer = root.findLayer(layer.id())
                    clone = vlayer.clone()
                    auxiliar.insertChildNode(0, clone)
                    root.removeChildNode(vlayer)
                elif layerTable == layer.name() and layerSchema == referencia.name():
                    print('entrou no referencia')
                    print(layerTable)
                    print(layerSchema)
                    vlayer = root.findLayer(layer.id())
                    clone = vlayer.clone()
                    referencia.insertChildNode(0, clone)
                    root.removeChildNode(vlayer)
                elif layerTable == layer.name() and layerSchema == ctgeo.name():
                    print('entrou no ctgeo')
                    print(layerTable)
                    print(layerSchema)
                    vlayer = root.findLayer(layer.id())
                    clone = vlayer.clone()
                    ctgeo.insertChildNode(0, clone)
                    root.removeChildNode(vlayer)

# Test to confirm if the layer is editable (connection is ok)
                layer.startEditing()                                                 
                if layer.isEditable():                                               
                    print('entrou no teste do lapis')
                    iface.vectorLayerTools().stopEditing(layer,False)                
                    break
```

Comment: The picture does not let you see when it `reg_inmobiliarios` enters `auxiliar` .. Can you add the content of `editable_layers` and `deleted_layers`?

Comment: Sure, added in the post!

Comment: That's pretty weird the code seems fine to me, can you run it one more time just to be sure? .. remove the print in the while, and change the the print after the while to `print('lt:{} ls:{} td:{} sd:{}', layerTable, layerSchema, deletedTable, deletedSchema)` and post the new log

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what you're trying to do here with your `editableLayers` and `deleted_layers`, but if the point is just to move existing layers to new groups, it is fairly simple:

```
root = QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot()
root.addGroup('auxiliar')
root.addGroup('ctgeo')
root.addGroup('referencia')

for layerNode in root.findLayers():
    schema = QgsDataSourceUri(layerNode.layer().source()).schema()
    group = root.findGroup(schema)
    if group:
        group.addChildNode(layerNode.clone())
        root.removeChildNode(layerNode)
```

Comment: With your suggestion worked, thanks, any idea why my code wasn't working?